# Repeated fsck in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: uefi

I am running a Toshiba satellite c70 laptop dual booting win10 and Ubuntu. I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04. It worked well for several weeks. Win10 still works OK. Now when I boot to Ubuntu 18.04 I get a black terminal screen with an error message indicating a problem loading uefi db x.509 certificate -65, and suggesting a manual fsck.  After the manual fsck the system detects orphan inodes and reports that the file system was modified.

After reboot the machine starts apparently normally except that a number of software packages won’t work; USB connections come up as “error creating mount point, read only file system”; Firefox reports to be running but not responding; LibreOffice won’t open. VLC works as normal.

When installing Ubuntu I had to deselect  Secure Boot in the UEFI menu security menu, I have now  tried both selecting and deselecting it with no effect.
Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

What happened next

I found a boot up work around by booting grub > Ubuntu advanced menu > recovery mode > then running dpgk and start. Normal functionality was restored, but the same trouble reappeared at each subsequent start up. That boot up worked about two times out of three.

After a bit of research I installed “Ubuntu Cleaner” through it’s ppa. Running “System” on the Janitor feature took quite a while but seemed to have effected a cure. I  booted up about 10 times, all seemed OK, but the old trouble then started again.

I eventually gave up on a fix, backed everything up on to a portable drive, and did a total reinstall of a fresh copy of 18.04. A couple of weeks down the line, that seems to have fixed it.